# Storage permission is not showing in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-storage

My app is targeting 33 and compile version also 33 and using flamingo android studio. In android studio following permission are not showing,

android.permission.Storage
android.permission.Read_Media_*

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Comment: How does a permission show?

Comment: I mean auto suggestion is not  showing, If manifest class (From sdk) have those permissions.

Comment: About which suggestions are you talking? I never saw a suggestion. And what would when go automatically? Why so vague? Come to the point.

Comment: Update your android studio to latest version. This will solve this issue.